# Replace a specific block of HTML between 2 files with Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have 2 HTML files that are similar, let's call them old.html and new.html.

I want to open new.html, do some processing, save a block of the html I just edited and replace the corresponding block in old.html.

So if new.html looks like:

```
<html>
<table>
my content
</table>
</html>
```

And old.html looks like:

```
<html>
<!--other html -->
<table>
old content
</table>
<!-- other html -->
```

Afterwards, old.html will look like:

```
<html>
<!--other html -->
<table>
my content
</table>
<!-- other html -->
```

I think I have the first part of this problem figured out, I just don't know how to actually modify the files.
I thought maybe somehow using some placeholder text would work, but I still don't know how to replace the original block of code from old.html

What I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from soupselect import select

new_file = "\\path\\to\\new.html"
old_file = "\\path\\to\\old.html"


f = open(new_file, "rb")
soup = Soup(f)
new_table = soup.table

f2 = open(old_file, "rb")
soup2 = Soup(f2)
old_table = soup2.table

#process new_table here

#how do i replace old_table with new_table?
f.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution uses reqular expressions and works for the simple example you gave above.  However, a complicated HTML file with LOTS of tables would require a more sophisticated solution.

Old HTML file

```
<html>
<!--other html -->
<table>
replace me
I'm old and weak
*cough*  can't.. hang.. on.. much... longer..
</table>
<!-- other html -->
```

New HTML file

```
<html>
<table>
I'm new content
replace old content with me
</table>
</html>
```

My Solution

```
import re

# open the files
Old = open('/somelocation/old.html').read()
New = open('/somelocation/new.html').read()

# get the strings you want to swap
NewTableContents = re.findall(r'<table>([\s\S]+?)</table>',New)[0]
OldTableContents = re.findall(r'<table>([\s\S]+?)</table>',Old)[0]

# replace
Replace = Old.replace(OldTableContents,NewTableContents)

# output string to new file
File = open('/somelocation/oldHTMLWithNewTableContents.html','w')
File.write(Replace)
File.close()
```

Resulting File

```
<html>
<!--other html -->
<table>
I'm new content
replace old content with me
</table>
<!-- other html -->
```

This example will work if there is a single table within each HTML file.  If there is more than one table per file you may have to get fancy depending on which tables you want to replace with which content.

Comment: Thanks! Thankfully, the files I'm working with will pretty much be guaranteed to only contain one table, so this is working out. I didn't consider using regular expressions. I was thinking I would need a library like BeautifulSoup to do some heavy lifting.